# How to make restart this loop , when user enters 1, and stop when 0

Tags: c++

I've  tried to get a number '6' generated inside a while loop, then count how many times this loop had to run before getting number 6, then if user inputs 1 this loop will run again, generate number 6 again and count how many tries, but the problem I'am facing is that when I enter 1 I'm getting same results as in previous loop.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdlib>    // random numbers header file//
#include <ctime>    // used to get date and time information
using namespace std;
int main()
{


int counter = 0;
int roll = 0;
int userChoice =1;
int total = 0;
float average = 0;
int programCounter = 0;
srand(time(0));

while (userChoice > 0)
{

    while (roll != 6)
    {

        roll = rand() % 6 + 1; // generate a random number  
        counter++;

    }
    total = total + counter;



    cout << "Do you want to continue?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter positive number to continue" << endl;
    cout << "To terminate enter 0" << endl;

    cin >> userChoice;


    programCounter++;

}

average = total / programCounter;
cout << "Avarage number of rolls before getting 6 is " <<  average;
```

}

my expected result is to get random number generator working again inside while loop and  to generate number 6 again, so later I can use number of rolls to count the average number of rolls before 6 was rolled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
while (roll != 6)
```

you check the condition before you roll the number. Once you rolled a 6, the condition will never be `false`.

In general it is good practice to declare variables only when you need them, and this would have avoided the bug in your code (also `counter` is not properly reset in your code):

```
int roll = 0;
int counter = 0;
while (roll != 6)
{
     roll = rand() % 6 + 1; // generate a random number  
     counter++;
}
```

Also note that for anything beyond simple toy randomness `rand` should be avoided. Use the facilities provided in `<random>` instead.

Comment: @xBlu3 consider to accept the answer if it answered your question